# PostgreSQL filter JSON column with mixed boolean and JSON values in it

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

My schema looks like this:

```sql
create table mytable
(
    id integer not null,
    value json not null
);
```

And the `value` column contains mixed data, both JSON and booleans like this:

```
id | value
----------
 1 | {"key1": 1, "key2": 2}
 2 | false
 3 | {"key2": 3}
 4 | true
```

These mixed values are accepted just fine by PostgreSQL.

Now I want to select all rows that either contain some json data or are `true`. I.e. I want to select rows 1, 3 and 4.

Here's the SQL query which I could come up with:

```sql
SELECT mytable.value
FROM mytable
WHERE CAST(CAST(mytable.value AS TEXT) AS BOOLEAN) IS NOT false;
```

But it fails with this message:

```
ERROR: argument of IS NOT FALSE must be type boolean, not type json
```

Comment: Your value false is not boolean but varchar (insert into mytable (id, value) values (4, true); fails, while insert into mytable (id, value) values (4, 'true'); works fine).

You can select all values that are not 'false' like this: SELECT mytable.value                                                                                                        
FROM mytable                                                                                      
WHERE mytable.value::text != 'false';

Comment: @HeikoJakubzik Good idea, I tried casting as above and it worked. Add an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value false is not `boolean` but `varchar` (`insert into mytable (id, value) values (4, true);` fails, while `insert into mytable (id, value) values (4, 'true');` works fine). 
You can select all values that are not `'false'` like this:

```
SELECT mytable.value FROM mytable WHERE mytable.value::text != 'false';
```

Comment: Slight correction... it's not `varchar`, it's `json`. Inserting `'true'` works because it can be cast successfully to JSON.

Comment: Consider to use `jsonb` type instead of `json`. It provides more possibilities including comparison of values, so your will be able to avoid explicit type casting `SELECT mytable.value FROM mytable WHERE mytable.value != 'false';`